# Javascript Enumerable query

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am getting accross this fiddle link about knockout [cascading dropdownlist](http://jsfiddle.net/Yrkbd/8/)

If I refer to this code:

```
viewModel.years = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    return Enumerable.From(makeModelList).Select(function(it) {
      return it.year;
    }).OrderBy(function(it) {
      return it.year;  
    }).Distinct().ToArray();
}, viewModel);
```

at the line the Enumerable.From().Select...

It is very much as a Linq expression call from C#, is it Javascript or Jquery ?

thanks if you have any link about it.

Cheers all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to look at [`underscorejs`](http://underscorejs.org/) or it's fork [lodash](http://lodash.com/). Coming from a .NET background myself, I know that `LINQ` is great and I really love it. However, those libraries I mentioned do pretty much the same thing but:

- have a much wider adoption in the JavaScript world
- receive more frequent updates
- and are just more well known by the community

I did the mistake and used one of those `LINQ` libraries and I really wish I hadn't because of the things that I outlined.

Comment: Hi, So if I understand, it is better to use underscorejs instead of linqJs, I have learn't something news to day thanks all of you !. Cheers

Comment: yep, it's at least my personal point of view. More features, more frequent updates, broader acceptance. Go for it :-)

Answer (score 1):

See [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) (LINQ for javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This is separate library linq.js. It allows you to use some .net LINQ feature in javascript

Read more:
http://linqjs.codeplex.com/